# How can I make a request for two different domains in the same module in NestJs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios, nestjs, httpservice

Today we have two different domains in our ecosystem. Our BFF should receive informations from those different endpoints.

If I add `FirstService` and `SecondService` in `providers`, both services get the same informations in `HttpModule.registerAsync`, but I must have two different `baseUrl`

`Module.ts`

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    HttpModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        timeout: 5000,
        maxRedirects: 5,
        baseURL: configService.get('SERVICE_URL_LEGACY'),
      }),
    }),
  ],
  providers: [FirstService, SecondService],
  controllers: [CampaignsController],
})
export class CampaignsModule {}
```

### Controller must be something like this

`Controller`

```js
export class CampaignsController {
  constructor(
    private readonly firstService: FirstService,
    private readonly secondService: SecondService,
  ) {}

  @Get('/review')
  async getReview() {
    const response = await this.firstService.getReview({});
    const responseTwo = await this.secondService.getReview({});
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's only ever going to be one `HttpModule` in `CampaignsModule`, and it would have *no way* to know which service invoked it.

If `FirstService` and `SecondService` were in different modules, you could work. configure an `HttpModule` for each one with the right settings. But that may not be right for you.

Otherwise you'd just have to send the `baseURL` in each time you use the `HttpService` like:

```
@Injectable()
export class FirstService {
  constructor(
    private readonly http: HttpService,
    config: ConfigService,
  ) {
    this.baseURL = config.get('SERVICE_URL_LEGACY')
  }

  async getReview() {
    return this.httpService.get('/whatever', { baseURL: this.baseURL }) 
  }
}
```